# Ubuntu 13.04 HDMI broken

Tags: upgrade, sound, 13.04, video, hdmi

I recently upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and ever since the upgrade the audio from my HDMI has not been working. It doesn't show up in the sound options as it did in 12.10 and it doesn't show up when running lspci. Futhermore, the HDMI has a hard time being recognized at all; meaning that it doesn't always add a video connection and instead doesn't react at all.

I haven't seen anyone else with the video problem. But i tried installing `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201305051134~raring1_all.deb` from [ALSA daily build snapshots](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages) as suggested here: [No sound via HDMI](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139459&page=3&p=12621337#post12621337) to try and fix the audio but with no luck.

I'm using a Lenovo B570, with an intel i5 2410M, intel HD 3000.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please try latest updated package (20130510) provided on :https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages

I installed it and works

Comment: I tried updating but it still doesn't work. I will probably just downgrade to 12.10.

Comment: Updated the package once again and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an AMD 6550D, and sound worked fine previously. It stopped working when I upgraded to 13.04.

It was a frustrating experience getting sound to work. First, I followed the instructions here:

http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/04/14/audio-over-hdmi-and-displayport-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Then, I changed some things with the BIOS sound settings a bit. I think this step was unnecessary, however, I did turn off the motherboard's non-HDMI sound card, which removed many useless options.

Finally, I followed the advice of the other poster, and installed a recent Alsa build, then rebooted. It was the "raring" build from May 17th here:

https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/

HDMI/Displayport finally showed up on "Sound Settings" under "System Settings", and sound was working. Oddly, the "Test Speaker" dialog still didn't work - I had to go to the "Sound Effects" tab to finally hear something!

Comment: Still no luck, but thanks. I think i will just downgrade to 12.10 and wait for 13.04 to become more stable.